# Meaning of "why should we take you over the next person"

Tags: meaning

I'm Chinese, and I can not fully understand the meaning of this sentence.
In the interview, does it mean "What is your advantage" or "Why we should accept you"?

Comment: Well. It's both. The two are not mutually exclusive. Indeed they are basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those are good explanations of the meaning. Taking you "over" someone else means to choose you and not someone else. So, the full meaning of the question would be, "why should we choose you instead of one of the other applicants."